# Coloring table rows - 3 rows, 3 different colors?

Tags: html, css

I want to set the background color of my table rows to 3 different colors, basically like this:

Row 1 - Red
Row 2 - Blue
Row 3 - White

Initally I've had only two different colors where I used this `tr:nth-child(2n+3) {background: #6bb8ff}`

But I guess this can't work for 3 different colors as for example the 6th row would match every 3rd and every 2nd row ?

Is there any other way to do this, or am I thinking too complicated ? :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:nth-child(3n+3)` for every third element.

Answer (score 2):

Why not, use classes to show the rows. If you're using a scripting language to output code, this shouldn't be too hard to implement

CSS:

```
<style>
.row1 {
background-color: #FF0000
}
.row2 {
background-color: #0000FF
}
.row3 {
background-color: #FFFFFF
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<table>
<tr class="row1"><td>Roeeels</td><td>Rofles</td></tr>
<tr class="row2"><td>Roeeels</td><td>Rofles</td></tr>
<tr class="row3"><td>Roeeels</td><td>Rofles</td></tr>
<tr class="row1"><td>Roeeels</td><td>Rofles</td></tr>
<tr class="row2"><td>Roeeels</td><td>Rofles</td></tr>
<tr class="row3"><td>Roeeels</td><td>Rofles</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
:nth-of-type(3n), :nth-of-type(3n+1),:nth-of-type(3n+2)
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr><td>Row1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row4</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row6</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row7</td></tr>
</table>

table tr:nth-child(3n+1)
{
 color:red;
}
table tr:nth-child(3n+2)
{
 color:blue; 
}
table tr:nth-child(3n+3)
{
 color:white; 
}
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/cLze226c/2/)